# Office 2016 - how can I see which Microsoft Account I use/change Microsoft Account?

Tags: ms-office, macos

In Office 2016, how can I see which Microsoft Account I use with it? The About box just shows a serial number and user details in the preferences is empty.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: "third-party (…) software when associated for use with Apple products" is on topic. Mac Office runs on Apple products.

Comment: From your own link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any Microsoft Office App (Word, in this case), click on the Avatar and it will bring up the Account you have signed in with and any other accounts it's connected to.

[image]